# JMeter BeanShell get EC2 instance ids

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and java so forgive my question if it seems elementary.  I'm trying to dynamically pull the EC instance id and IP for a specific named AWS Ec2 instance in Jmeter.  Using either a beanshell or JS223 sampler.   I can connect and create the ec2Cilent - but I'm able to find the syntax to get the available information for any ec2.  any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This is probably not the best site for this question, since your main problem appears to be the AWS APIs rather than testing practices. I'm recommending it be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You want the "describe-instances" command.  See [this documentation for example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html).

Comment: do you want to get the EC2 instance id of a local machine or remote one ?. Please share the complete scenario info (steps to do it manually). Based on that I will share solution as JMeter can do it in number of ways.

Comment: @KatePaulk - Question is combination of Jmeter + Amazone AWS so seems hard to decide whether it is off topic or not :) Because Jmeter is part of QA.